# Wordpress, загрузка картинок

Tags: wordpress, изображения, acf

Не могу загрузить ни одно изображение в wordpress. Пытался загрузить через медиафайлы, через записи, через acf выдает одну и ту же ошибку "Во время загрузки произошла ошибка. Пожалуйста, повторите попытку позже." Даже если закину файл напрямую в папку Uploads то загрузить от туда файлы не могу.

Comment: Проблема была решена. Дело оказалось в битой базе данных в которую не загружались картинки

Answer (score 0):

Какая версия Wordpress и какую систему используете: Windows, Mac, Ubuntu?
Проверьте в php.ini есть ли imagemagick.
Если нет и используете Ubuntu то выполните:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```